# Use spring-data-elasticsearch annotations with Jackson ObjectMapper?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jackson, spring-data-elasticsearch

Suppose there are some POJOs to be written to an Elasticsearch index. From my limited experience with ES, each field gets a type (e.g. text, keyword, ...). Is it possible to configure the Jackson ObjectMapper with the annotations from spring-data-elasticsearch to customize the type of the serialized Json? As an example:

```
@Document(indexName = "books", type = "book")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    String isbn;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    String title;
}
```

Then the mapping should include something like

```
{
  "mappings":
    {
        "book": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "title": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I think about this wrong!

Comment: Ftm I work around this issue by posting the mappings, settings etc. directly to the index before pushing any documents.

Answer (score 4):

**With Elasticsearch** you can either let it define mappings automatically using **[Dynamic Mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-mapping.html)** (you persist your docs and ES builds mapping according to it input), or you can define your schema prior to indexing **by sending ES with relevant mappings/templates** (.json files).

**Using dynamic mapping option is less recommended** and might cause issues with mappings (wrong date format, int/float issues, etc..)

I usually set my mappings without the dynamic feature - setting it to 'strict', this will raise Exception automatically by ES (and will propagate with any library you use)

```
"dynamic": "strict",
```

> strict: If new fields are detected, an exception is thrown and the document is rejected. New fields must be explicitly added to the mapping.

**With Spring-Data-Elasticsearch**, you can define your Object just the way you have posted - annotating your fields with wanted types - this will cause ElasticsearchTemplate.java to parse your Object (take a look at `public <T> boolean putMapping(Class<T> clazz) and public ElasticsearchPersistentEntity getPersistentEntityFor(Class clazz)`) and feed it to ES.

You can verify spring-es index/mapping creation according to your annotations with ElasticsearchTemplate:
(Test taken from [Spring-Data-ES project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ElasticsearchTemplateTests.java))

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnMappingForGivenEntityClass() {

    // given

    // when
    boolean created = elasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(SampleEntity.class);
    elasticsearchTemplate.putMapping(SampleEntity.class);
    Map<String, Object> mapping = elasticsearchTemplate.getMapping(SampleEntity.class);

    // then
    assertThat(created).isTrue();
    assertThat(mapping).isNotNull();
    assertThat(((Map<String, Object>) ((Map<String, Object>) mapping.get("properties")).get("message")).get("type"))
            .isEqualTo("text");
}
```

And the SampleEntity:

```
@Document(indexName = "test-index-sample-mapping", type = "mapping")
static class SampleMappingEntity {

    @Id private String id;

    @Field(type = Text, index = false, store = true, analyzer = "standard")
    private String message;
}
```

I would recommend **separating index construction from the application** and not to use the implicit POJO annotation option - this will be easier to control later on.

Comment: Thanks, will try that out when I get the chance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version of Spring Data Elasticsearch you are using; the support of using the Jackson Object Mapper together with the `@Field` annotation is limited.

If you are using 3.2.0RC1, then change to use the `ElasticsearchEntityMapper` (see [reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.2.0.RC1/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping) how to configure it). Although the Jackson Mapper still is the default one if no other is configured, current work is done on `ElasticsearchEntityMapper`. I think after release of 3.2 we probably will change the default mapper to `ElasticsearchEntityMapper`.

I know the reference documentation still lacks information, I'm just in the process of reworking it.

When creating an index with the Repository classes from 3.2, the annotations like `@Field` are taken into account and the correct mapping is written to the index, no need to write the mapping by yourself.